# Timing on GET info from PHP/SQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

Just for you to know I'm less than a newbie!

I have the following javascript code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    renderTime();
    getsec(myHandler);
    countdown('countdown');
    ...
}
function myHandler(resultado) {
    seconds = resultado;
}
function reqListener () {
    console.log(this.responseText);
}
function getsec(callback) {
    var indice = 1;
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    oReq.onload = function() {
        var variarr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        callback(variarr[0]);
    };
    oReq.open("GET", "getsec.php?lei="+indice, true);
    oReq.send();
}
```

This works perfectly for me. The intention is to get data from MySQL table through getsec.php every second. As you can see I have function countdown('countdown') that looks like this:

```
function countdown(element) {
    ...
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        ...
        if( runned == false){ // This condition happens
            ...
        } else {
            ...
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

I tryed to put function getsec(myHandler) inside function countdown('countdown')

```
        if( runned == false){ // This condition happens
            getsec(myHandler);
```

and I stop getting the information I want.
Can anyone explain me why?

Comment: Why do you want the callback to be a variable rather than just making it `myHandler` all the time? and why doesn't `myHandler` actually do anything with the data?

Comment: Please be patient with me @developerwjk, I'm trying to understand how "these things" work by applying what I learn step by step.  I wanted to get MySQL data every second and, after many fails, I took this code from stackoverflow, changed it and finnaly got it working. I used here as an example a variable - seconds but there's more. I use these variables further (where I put ...) in code. Hope I understood you.

Comment: Is "runned" set anywhere, or used anywhere else?

Comment: As functions **getsec(myHandler)** and **countdown('countdown')** run on **window.onload** (every second), why does **getsec(myHandler)** stops working when called inside **countdown('countdown')**???

Comment: @Blah Argh **runned** is set under condition and I test it and it's **false**. The rest of the code (...) works perfectly, only **getsec(myHandler)** stops working.

Comment: If you change "if(runned==false)" to "if(!runned)", does it work? Also, do you have error reporting on?

Comment: I'm sorry! Perhaps I didn't explain correctly. Inside the condition **if( runned == false){** there's many code instructions where the first one is **getsec(myHandler);**. Just this one doesn't work! All the other coding works. I just choosed not to show it here because is too extensive. By the way, your way **if(!runned)**, has the same effect.